# Ordering of events from addGlobalMonitorForEvents

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsevent

I am trying to monitor mouse click events like so:

```
clickMonitor = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(
  matching: [.leftMouseDown, .rightMouseDown, .leftMouseUp, .rightMouseUp]) {
    [unowned self] event in
   ...
```

However, it appears that my events are coming in out of order. For instance, often for a double-click, I get two `.leftMouseDown` events (with counts 1 and 2) before I get either `.leftMouseUp` event.

Are there any guarantees to ensure the ordering that these events will come in? If not, is there any mechanism for ordering them?

Comment: What is the timeStamp of the events?